# Find dimension of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}, i)$ over $\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, extension-field

One of the tasks that I have is to first (1) find the minimal polynomial of $\sqrt{2} + i$ over $\mathbb{Q}$, and (2) find the degree of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}, i)$ over $\mathbb{Q}$, i.e. $[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}, i) : \mathbb{Q}]$.

For (1), I first find the minimal polynomial as follows: If $x = \sqrt{2} + i$, then
\begin{align*}
x^2 &= (\sqrt{2} + i)^2 \\ 
x^2 &= 2 + 2\sqrt{2}i - 1 = 1 + 2\sqrt{2}i \\ 
x^2 - 1 &= 2\sqrt{2}i \\ 
(x^2 - 1)^2 &= (2\sqrt{2}i))^2 \\ 
x^4 - 2x^2 + 1 &= -4 \\
x^4 - 2x^2 + 5 &= 0
\end{align*}
So the minimal polynomial of $\sqrt{2} + i$ is $x^4 - 2x^2 + 5 = 0$.

Now for (2), I know I can use the fact that
\begin{equation*}
[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}, i) : \mathbb{Q}] = [\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}, i) : \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2} + i)][\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2} + i) : \mathbb{Q}]
\end{equation*}
in which because $x^4 - 2x^2 + 5$ is the minimal polynomial of $\sqrt{2} + i$ over $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2} + i)$, then $[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2} + i) : \mathbb{Q}] = 4$. Now the only issue that I am running into is to show that $[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}, i) : \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2} + i)] = 1$. Some help would be much appreciated!

Comment: $(2\sqrt2)^2=2\times \sqrt2\times 2 \times \sqrt 2=8$

Comment: You have shown that $\sqrt{2}+i$ satisfies $x^4-2x^2+5$. But you have not shown that this is its minimal polynomial. In other words you are missing a proof that $x^4-2x^2+5$ is irreducible. This is the crucial step, all the rest is just calculations.

Answer (score 4):

It suffices to show that $[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2},i):\mathbb{Q}]=4$. We have $$[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2},i):\mathbb{Q}]=[\mathbb{Q}(i,\sqrt{2}):\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})][\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}):\mathbb{Q}]=2.2=4,$$
in which $[\mathbb{Q}(i,\sqrt{2}):\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})]=2$ since $[\mathbb{Q}(i,\sqrt{2}):\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})]\leq 2$ and it can not be $1$ since $i\not \in \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}).$

Comment: I would add a short explanation to the last claim. $i\notin\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$ because $\mathbb{R}$ is a subfield of $\mathbb{C}$ that contains $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\sqrt{2}$, and so by definition $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})\subseteq\mathbb{R}$. Because in general it's difficult to say whether some element belongs to a field or not. It is with $i$ that we have this easy explanation. Replace $i$ by $\sqrt{3}$, and we would have to make some computations to prove it is not in $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$.

Answer (score 3):

It is trivial that $\mathbb Q\left(\sqrt2+i\right)\subset \mathbb Q\left(\sqrt2,i\right)$. Convsersely, since
$$\frac 3{\sqrt 2+i}=\sqrt2-i,$$
we know that $\sqrt2-i$ belongs to $\mathbb Q\left(\sqrt2+i\right)$ and hence $\sqrt2$ and $i$ are in $\mathbb Q\left(\sqrt2+i\right)$.

Answer (score 1):

Your original question seems to be about just the dimension of $K=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2},i)$ over $\mathbb{Q}$, not about finding a primitive element for $K$.

If so, to conclude that $[K:\mathbb{Q}]=4$ is enough to note that we have a tower
$$
\mathbb{Q}\subset\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})\subset\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2},i)
$$
since each step is quadratic and the degree is multiplicative on towers.

Answer (score 0):

It's obvious that $\sqrt 2 + i \in \Bbb Q(\sqrt 2,i)$, so $\Bbb Q(\sqrt 2+i)\subseteq \Bbb Q(\sqrt 2,i)$.

On the other hand, $i = \frac{1}{6}\left((i+\sqrt{2})+\left(\sqrt{2}+i\right)^3\right)\in\Bbb Q(\sqrt 2+i)$ and $\sqrt 2 = \frac{1}{6} \left(5
   \left(\sqrt{2}+i\right)-\left(\sqrt{2}+i\right)^3\right)\in\Bbb Q(\sqrt 2+i)$, so $\Bbb Q(\sqrt 2,i)\subseteq \Bbb Q(\sqrt 2+i)$

Then $\Bbb Q(\sqrt 2,i) = \Bbb Q(\sqrt 2+i)$.